# How to run Python to reckognize module hierarchy for Airflow DAGs?

Tags: python, airflow, python-import

A have several DAGs of similar structure and I wanted to use advice described in Airflow docs as [Modules Management](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/modules_management.html):

> This is an example structure that you might have in your dags folder:
>
> ```
> <DIRECTORY ON PYTHONPATH>
> | .airflowignore  -- only needed in ``dags`` folder, see below
> | -- my_company
>               | __init__.py
>               | common_package
>               |              |  __init__.py
>               |              | common_module.py
>               |              | subpackage
>               |                         | __init__.py
>               |                         | subpackaged_util_module.py
>               |
>               | my_custom_dags
>                              | __init__.py
>                              | my_dag1.py
>                              | my_dag2.py
>                              | base_dag.py
> ```
>
> In the case above, these are the ways you could import the python
> files:
>
> ```
> from my_company.common_package.common_module import SomeClass
> from my_company.common_package.subpackage.subpackaged_util_module import AnotherClass
> from my_company.my_custom_dags.base_dag import BaseDag
> ```

That works fine in Airflow.

However I used to validate my DAGs locally by running (also as advised by a piece of documentation - [DAG Loader Test](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#dag-loader-test)):

```
python my_company/my_custom_dags/my_dag1.py
```

When using the imports, it complains:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/[...]/my_company/my_custom_dags/my_dag1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from my_company.common_package.common_module import SomeClass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_company'
```

How should I run it so that it understands the context and reckognizes the package?

Comment: I faced a similar issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: As described in answer below, adjusting PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

It works when run this way:

```
PYTHONPATH=. python my_company/my_custom_dags/my_dag1.py
```

It seems that when entry point is `my_dag1.py` that's inside `my_company/my_custom_dags` Python considers it as its "working directory" and only looks for modules within that path. When I add `.` to `PYTHONPATH` it can also look at entire directory structure and reckognize module `my_company` and below.

(I'm not expert in Python, so above explanation might be somewhat innacurrate, but this is my understanding. I'm also not sure if that's indeed the cleanest way to make it work)